# How to use downloaded fonts in scss?

Tags: css, sass

I have downloaded the font and now I want use it in my project which I am working. I don't want to use it via @font-face. Is there any way to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it as in import....I usually have a scss partial containing font imports, like `_font.scss` and then `@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap");`

and then reference the font in my `_vars.scss` and then create variable containing the font family `$font-default: "Barlow", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, -apple-system;`

and in my `main.scss` just make sure to call both...

`@import "~styles/core_styles/vars";`
`@import "~styles/core_styles/fonts";`

Comment: how about a practical approach? please link a video where i can see how things happen since i am a beginner of scss.

Comment: That is about as simple as I can describe it, instructional videos are available here https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-sass.